# Periodic, Infinitely Differentiable Function Dense in $L^2$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, periodic-functions

I have encountered an interesting question, which seems to have a simple solution.

Consider $E$ as the set of $2\pi$ periodic, complex-valued, infinitely differentiable functions s.t. $\forall f\in E$, $f(0)=0$ and $$\int_{[0,2\pi]} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx = 0$$. Show that $E$ is dense in $(L^2([0, 2\pi)), \|\cdot\|_2)$ using the fact that a subspace of Hilbert space is dense iff $E^\perp = \{0\}$.

The setting of this problem reminds me of much of its Taylor Series. The fact that the function is $0$ at origin removes the first term of its expansion. I would like to use the hint to show nonzero functions $g$ would give positive inner-product with some well-chosen $f$, yet I could not do this rigorously. Could someone help?

Comment: What does $f(0) = 0$ mean in $L^2$?

Comment: I think there is no meaning to say a function $g\in L^2$ to have specific value at a certain point since $L^2$ is defined as the equivalent classes of functions. Yet there is meaning to say $f(0)=0$ since $f$ is a particular function instead of a class.

Comment: You should probably add the smooth part to the body of the question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions
$$
e_n(x) = xe^{2i\pi nx}, \quad x \in [0,2\pi],
$$
for $n \geq 1$ are in $E$. Therefore, if $f \in E^{\perp}$, then for all $n \geq 1$,
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} f(x) e_n(x) \: \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{2 \pi} f(x) x e^{2i\pi nx} \: \mathrm{d}x = 0.
$$
By this means that the function $x \mapsto x f(x)$ has all its Fourier coefficients, except the constant one, equal to $0$. This means that it is a constant function. So for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$, we have $f(x) = c/x$, but since $f \in L^2$, the only option is that $c = 0$, i.e. $f = 0$.